# How to import data from a different workbook, with a button. getSheetById(id) doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to import data from 3 sheets in a different workbook, in the same drive, to a newer workbook, with the press of a button.

Each workbooks has a sheet called 'Log Wizard' with 2 boxes. The bottom box displays the current spreadsheet key. The top box is an input field to paste an existing sheet key into.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1833-5CnOurssETuZFtohiHRRBx1V3_95_L0S-f9vPLk/edit#gid=187106606

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hnsZ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U55mw.jpg)

So far, I cannot figure out how to make a script that does the following:

- When the button is pressed, get the source sheet id which is provided by the user in cell M11 of the current sheet, and use that to access the referenced spreadsheet
- And then copy 3 different ranges from three different sheets (2 of which are hidden) to empty sheets of the same names in the newer workbook (vehicle configuration, budget log and log).

I know that getSheetById has issues with permissions of some sort. I am not very familiar with google scripting so any help is appreciated.

```
//variables
var id = "123456789abcdefg";
var sheet = "LOG WIZARD";
var cells = "M11:AB13";
var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheet).getRange(cells);
var id = range.getSheet().getParent().getId();

//custom function to import logs
function importlogs() {

//Source sheet from which to import from
var is = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
var sheet1i = is.getSheetByName("BUDGET LOG");
var sheet2i = is.getSheetByName("LOG");

//Current sheet from which to export to
var xs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1x = xs.getSheetByName("BUDGET LOG");
var sheet2x = xs.getSheetByName("LOG");

//Copy and paste contents of import Budget Log sheet to export Budget Log sheet
sheet1i.getRange("A3:AO").copyTo(sheet1x.getRange(sheet1x.getLastRow()+1,1,1,7), {contentsOnly:true});

//Copy and paste contents of import Log sheet to export Log sheet
sheet2i.getRange("A3:O").copyTo(sheet2x.getRange(sheet2x.getLastRow()+1,1,1,7), {contentsOnly:true});

}
```

I am unsure if it is actually passing the key correctly or at all. I tend to get the error **Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp.** or **Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (line 5).**

I assume this is because of some type of permission that doesn't allow a custom function to call another spreadsheet?

I have tried various suggestions here:
[You do not have permission to call openById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587331/you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-openbyid)

and here:
[How to use an installable trigger to get SpreadsheetApp.openById(id) to work, by calling it from a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73923581/how-to-use-an-installable-trigger-to-get-spreadsheetapp-openbyidid-to-work-by/73924168?noredirect=1#comment130561957_73924168)

but so far nothing I have found works.

Answer (score 1):

The `//variables` section is in the global scope of the script project, so those definitions get evaluated *every* time *any* function runs, just before the function executes.

The problem is that those definitions are not compatible with the [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) you are using. A custom function runs in a limited context where methods that require authorization are not available. When `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)` gets called in that context, the custom function errors out, even though the problematic line of code is not within the function itself.

The `importlogs()` function is run through a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets). It will run in an authorized context where `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)` is available normally.

To solve the problem, delete the `//variables` section. The same declarations are repeated within `importlogs()`, so that should be enough. If you want to improve the `importlogs()` function, use the code given to you in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73924168/13045193).

You may want to add this code to easily call the `importLogs_()` function through a button:

```
/**
* Call this function through a button.
* https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets
*/
function runImportLogs() {
  const sourceSsId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getRange('LOG WIZARD!M11')
    .getDisplayValue();
  importLogs_(sourceSsId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

I "replaced" the variables section with the code you suggested. I am getting this error: **ReferenceError: importLogs_ is not defined.**

Comment: Include the `importLogs_()` function given in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73924168/13045193). See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I read about append rows and I cannot make heads for tails of it. I get this error:

Error ReferenceError: appendRows_ is not defined (anonymous) @ importLogs.gs:26 importLogs_ @ importLogs.gs:24 runImportLogs @ importLogs.gs:9

Comment: As the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73924168/13045193) tells, you will need to paste the [appendRows_()](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219) utility function in the script project. Alternatively, use your own code to write rows to the end of the sheet. See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) to learn more.

Comment: Ok, I have played along. I obviously am not going to sift through the entire apps script library in pursuit of answering my question. I was clear from the beginning what I am trying to do, and first you goaded me into creating a new question. I don't know what "pasting the utility function means". If you are unable or unwilling to break things down in generic terms, then thank you for your time, I no longer require your specific assistance.

Comment: There is no need to be rude. The advice above is given with the best intentions. As the answer says, you can simply delete the problematic `//variables` section, which should already be enough to make your existing code work. Optionally, _If you want to improve the code_, follow the rest of the advice. Please understand that Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for _programmers_. A basic understanding of how to write and edit code is required. See the [charter](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).